# Masonry doesn't work properly after display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm currently using Masonry to make a list,
here's my problem...

I have some different type of `div` content,
and I want it to display only one type of them at once.

The way I do is apply `display:none` on the div which are filtered out by javascript, and apply `display:block` on the chosen `div`.

But weird is after I call Masonry, it makes all of the visible `div` line up in one column, which is not what i expected...

here's my code:

```js
$(function() {
 
  let m = $('#masonry');
  let item = $('.item');
  
  m.masonry({
   itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: 0
  });
  
  $('#false').on('click', function() {
   for(let i = 0; i < item.length; i ++) {
     $(item[i]).show();
    }
  
   for(let i = 0; i < item.length; i ++) {
      if($(item[i]).data('hide') != false) {
        $(item[i]).hide();
      } else {
        $(item[i]).show();
      }
    }
    m.masonry();
  })
  
  $('#true').on('click', function() {

   for(let i = 0; i < item.length; i ++) {
     $(item[i]).show();
    }
    
    for(let j = 0; j < item.length; j ++) {
     if($(item[j]).data('hide') != true) {
       $(item[j]).hide();
      } else {
       $(item[j]).show();
      }
    }
    m.masonry();
  })
  
  $('#pooo').on('click', function() {

   for(let i = 0; i < item.length; i ++) {
     $(item[i]).show();
    }
    
    for(let j = 0; j < item.length; j ++) {
     if($(item[j]).data('hide') != null) {
       $(item[j]).hide();
      } else {
       $(item[j]).show();
      }
    }
    m.masonry();
  })
})
```

```css
.item {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 20%;
}

.inner {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>

<div id="masonry">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-hide="null">
    <div class="inner"><br><br><br><br><br></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-hide="true">
    <div class="inner"><br><br><br></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-hide="false">
    <div class="inner"><br><br><br><br><br></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-hide="true">
    <div class="inner"><br><br><br></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-hide="null">
    <div class="inner"><br><br><br><br><br></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-hide="true">
    <div class="inner"><br><br><br><br></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-hide="false">
    <div class="inner"><br><br><br><br></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-hide="null">
    <div class="inner"><br><br><br></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-hide="false">
    <div class="inner"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="false">false</button>
<button id="true">true</button>
<button id="pooo">pooo</button>
```

Any suggests?

Comment: OK... I found this may be caused by hiding the first masonry item... And I'm working on it, wish me luck. XD

Answer (score 1):

OK, my assumption in comment is right,
And Masonry already has a solution for it, which is `columnWidth`.

By simply add a `div` with the width I want as a reference for the `columnWidth`'s value e.g.`$.masonry({columnWidth: '#theDivWithWidth'})` and it should do the trick...

Case close I think XD